# Commit and delete form database on start/stop off Application

Tags: android

I am trying to read data from the `SQLiteDatabase` when my application opens, and commit it all by inserting all of the changes when the Application closes.  I know this isn't the most efficient, but the assignment I am working on is about UI mostly, not how the back-end works.  How can I go about doing this?  I tried creating my own `Service` class, but then I soon discovered that I can't seem to use the constructor for the Service. My goal is to use some kind of `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` functions to work with the database when the App is started/ended.

Comment: Why not just use `onCreate` and `onSuspend/onResume` of the main launch activity?

Comment: I have multiple `Activity`'s

Comment: To do it in an activity, look at the activity lifecycle here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html  Using a service and e.g. sending the data in an intent (if it isn't too much data) is another option

Comment: @MichaelButscher That's what I was trying to do, but I don't see anyway to do it with custom variables at the moment.

Comment: It is impossible to do anything when an application (as a whole) closes because it is just killed

Comment: You can still do this with `onCreate` and `onDestroy` of the main launch activity.

Comment: "I have multiple Activity's" -- so? Each activity loads its own data (or obtains it from a central cache). Each activity persists its own data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the situation like yours, the best approach is to use  `onPause()` as [described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState):

> Note: Because onSaveInstanceState() is not guaranteed to be called, you should use it only to record the transient state of the activity (the state of the UI)—you should never use it to store persistent data. Instead, you should use onPause() to store persistent data (such as data that should be saved to a database) when the user leaves the activity